# How can I automate rexx scripts in mainframe using python

Tags: python, automation, scripting, mainframe, rexx

I want to automate rexx scripts using python eventually I want to automate the mainframe login.

I am totally new to mainframe.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is 2 separate questions, and neither are explained very well. 1) What do you mean by automate a REXX script? A REXX exec (it's not a script) is itself automation, so what aspect of it do you want to automate? Also Python is not available on the z/OS side of the mainframe (it is available on USS). 2) Logons - there really isn't anything to automate. You connect, enter a userid and password and you're on, just like a Linux system.

Comment: so we cannot install python on a mainframe db2 database ? what I want is to replace the rexx scripts with python that is all the tasks now I want to do with python , for that I need to connect my mainframe db2 database to python, how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure about what you are doing, but from what you have asked i would go from 2 ways, if you are really willing to use python, i would use the Zowe SDK for python to run tso commands and call the REXX you would like to use. You can learn more about it here:
https://github.com/zowe/zowe-client-python-sdk#tso

Otherwise i would call the rexx you are willing to execute from a JCL.